# Docker - Mysql + PHP erro na hora de conectar com o mysql

Tags: docker

Estou aprendendo um pouco sobre Docker, mas tive alguns problemas na conexão com o Mysql.

Segue o arquivo docker-compose.yml

```
php:
  build: .
  ports:
   - "8082:80"
  volumes:
   - ./www:/var/www/html
  links:
   - db
db:
  image: mysql:5.7
  ports:
   - "3306:3306"
  volumes:
   - ./var/lib/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
  environment:
   - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=phprs
   - MYSQL_DATABASE=phprs
```

E o arquivo Dockerfile

```
FROM php:5.6-apache
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo_mysql mysql pdo
```

Segue a mensagem de erro:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
```

E o código do index.php

```
<?php

define( 'MYSQL_HOST', '127.0.0.1' );
define( 'MYSQL_USER', 'root' );
define( 'MYSQL_PASSWORD', 'phprs' );
define( 'MYSQL_DB_NAME', 'phprs' );

try
{
    $PDO = new PDO( 'mysql:host=' . MYSQL_HOST . ';dbname=' . MYSQL_DB_NAME . ';port=3306', MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASSWORD );


}
catch ( PDOException $e )
{
    echo 'Erro ao conectar com o MySQL: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Como eu faço para ver os logs de erro do mysql, e do apache?

Obrigado galera :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu mysql não será acessível via localhost (127.0.0.1)  pois ele está em outro [container](https://www.docker.com/what-container), esse container funciona como um isolamento stand-alone de serviços,ambiente e rede.

Há 2 formas de fazer já que você está usando o [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/): 
você pode tentar acessar usando `db`  (nome do seu container mysql) como hostname alterando no docker-compose.yml

```
links:
       - mysql:mysql
```

E no PHP:

```
define( 'MYSQL_HOST', 'mysql' );
```

Ou então definir um ip para que os containers conver-sem usando os ips préviamente definidos:

```
version: "3.0"

networks:
  mynet:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
     config:
       - subnet: 10.2.0.0/16

services:
    php:
      build: .
      ports:
       - "8082:80"
      volumes:
       - ./www:/var/www/html
      links:
       - mysql:mysql
      networks:
        mynet:
            ipv4_address: 10.2.0.2
    mysql:
      image: mysql:5.7
      ports:
       - "3306:3306"
      volumes:
       - ./var/lib/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
      environment:
       - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=phprs
       - MYSQL_DATABASE=phprs
      networks:
        mynet:
            ipv4_address: 10.2.0.3
```

Dentro do grupo networks foi criado uma rede chamada "mynet" ela utiliza o drive bridge,o que significa que essa rede está visível para o host e usará essa mesma rede para conectar-se à redes externas ao host.
No grupo service foi adicionado a propriedade de network e um ipv4 foi definido para cada serviço.

Comment: Muito obrigado LeonanCarvalho funcionou!